# Can I get JSON LD data from google search?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json-ld

I am hoping to play around withe Alexa's AWS Lambda functions and was wondering if I can extract the JSON LD event data that is populating the First Avenue Calendar site?

https://www.google.com/search?q=first+avenue+calendar&oq=first+avenue+calendar&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i60l3j0l2.3727j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

I'm not sure if this is possible or where to start, any thoughts?

Comment: Doubtful. Google makes it incredibly difficult to scrape any data from their searches. If it's not in an official API, you're likely out of luck.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

Scraping such data is trivial though unreliable. Should take a couple of lines of JS code running in chrome developer tools:

Here is something to get you started (the class names _Kjf and Kjg will need to be updated everytime google updates their search, thus the unreliability):

```
let obj = [];
for (const n of document.getElementsByClassName('_Kjf')) {
    const date = n.getElementsByClassName('_Kjg')[0].innerText;
    const title = n.getElementsByClassName('title')[0].innerText;
    const time = n.getElementsByClassName('_Jjg')[0].innerText;
    obj.push({date, time, title});
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2));
```

results:

```
[
  {
    "date": "Tue, Jan 16",
    "time": "7:00 PM",
    "title": "YUMI ZOUMA"
  },
  {
    "date": "Wed, Jan 17",
    "time": "7:00 PM",
    "title": "ASHLEY GROVES Album Release Show"
  },
  {
    "date": "Thu, Jan 18",
    "time": "7:00 PM",
    "title": "SLØTFACE"
  },
  {
    "date": "Fri, Jan 19",
    "time": "9:00 PM",
    "title": "A DJ Tribute to THE PURPLE ONE and THE KING OF POP ft. DJ DAVE PAUL and DJ MARCO"
  },
  {
    "date": "Sat, Jan 20",
    "time": "8:00 PM",
    "title": "THE FUNK HUNTERS"
  },
  {
    "date": "Sun, Jan 21",
    "time": "7:00 PM",
    "title": "NEON DREAMS"
  },
  {
    "date": "Mon, Jan 22",
    "time": "7:00 PM",
    "title": "TY DAVIS - ARTeries Release Show"
  },
  {
    "date": "Wed, Jan 24",
    "time": "7:00 PM",
    "title": "DRIFTWOOD PYRE, SEAFARER, THE CULT OF LIP, and BLACK SATORI"
  },
  {
    "date": "Thu, Jan 25",
    "time": "7:00 PM",
    "title": "LAST IMPORT Release Show"
  },
  {
    "date": "Fri, Jan 26",
    "time": "8:00 PM",
    "title": "RYAN KINDER"
  },
  {
    "date": "Sat, Jan 27",
    "time": "8:00 PM",
    "title": "YUNG GRAVY"
  },
  {
    "date": "Sun, Jan 28",
    "time": "7:30 PM",
    "title": "MAKO - Breathe Tour"
  },
  {
    "date": "Mon, Jan 29",
    "time": "7:30 PM",
    "title": "VINNY CROOK$"
  },
  {
    "date": "Tue, Jan 30",
    "time": "7:30 PM",
    "title": "BLACK GENESIS"
  },
  {
    "date": "Wed, Jan 31",
    "time": "9:00 PM",
    "title": "Beyoncé vs Rihanna Dance Party"
  },
  {
    "date": "Wed, Feb 7",
    "time": "8:00 PM",
    "title": "Magic Giant"
  },
  {
    "date": "Thu, Feb 8",
    "time": "8:00 PM",
    "title": "ZZ Ward"
  },
  {
    "date": "Fri, Feb 9",
    "time": "8:00 PM",
    "title": "flor"
  },
  {
    "date": "Sun, Feb 11",
    "time": "8:00 PM",
    "title": "Flint Eastwood"
  },
  {
    "date": "Tue, Feb 13",
    "time": "5:30 PM",
    "title": "Neck Deep"
  },
  {
    "date": "Wed, Feb 14",
    "time": "8:00 PM",
    "title": "Rostam"
  },
  {
    "date": "Fri, Feb 16",
    "time": "9:00 PM",
    "title": "Rebelution"
  },
  {
    "date": "Sat, Feb 17",
    "time": "8:00 PM",
    "title": "Valerie June"
  },
  {
    "date": "Tue, Feb 20",
    "time": "8:30 PM",
    "title": "Majid Jordan"
  },
  {
    "date": "Wed, Feb 21",
    "time": "8:00 PM",
    "title": "Polica"
  },
  {
    "date": "Thu, Feb 22",
    "time": "8:00 PM",
    "title": "Machine Head"
  },
  {
    "date": "Fri, Feb 23",
    "time": "8:00 PM",
    "title": "ANI DIFRANCO with Gracie and Rachel"
  },
  {
    "date": "Sat, Feb 24",
    "time": "9:00 PM",
    "title": "Porches."
  },
  {
    "date": "Wed, Feb 28",
    "time": "8:30 PM",
    "title": "Autograf"
  },
  {
    "date": "Fri, Mar 2",
    "time": "9:00 PM",
    "title": "Tune-Yards"
  },
  {
    "date": "Mon, Mar 5",
    "time": "8:00 PM",
    "title": "EarthGang"
  },
  {
    "date": "Tue, Mar 6",
    "time": "7:00 PM",
    "title": "Why Don't We"
  }
]
```